# Timer App Type Error I Can't See

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

I'm quite new to python I have run into a type error but I personally can't see it. Help will be appreciated. I am using windows 7.

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Kids\Desktop\Python Tests\Clock2.py", line 18, in mclock
    mlable = Label(mGui, str(z), "minute(s) has past.").pack()
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from time import sleep

def mclock():
    x = 1
    z = 0
    while x != -1:
        mlable = Label(mGui,text = "str(x) second(s)").pack()
        x = x+1
        sleep(1)
        if x == 60:
            x = 1
            z = z+1
        mlable = Label(mGui, str(z), "minute(s) has past.").pack()
    return

mGui = Tk()

mGui.geometry("300x200+100+100")
mGui.title("Jono's Clock")

menubar = Menu(mGui)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Clock",command = mclock)

menubar.add_cascade(label = "File",menu = filemenu)
mGui.config(menu = menubar)

mGui.mainloop()
```

Also if any one knows haw to add a clear function to clear the seconds each time it ticks that will be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label initializer, like all Python methods, has a `self` first arguments. It accepts only up to *two* additional positional arguments (the master and `cfg` arguments), but you are giving 3:

```
Label(mGui, str(z), "minute(s) has past.")
```

You probably wanted to concatenate those two strings; you'll have to pass this in explicitly as the `text` keyword argument:

```
Label(mGui, text=str(z) + " minute(s) has past.")
```

Comment: I have tried changing it but all that happens now is it crashes with no error after I start the clock/timer. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't exit it just say stopped responding (task manager).

Comment: Ah, that's because `mclock` *never returns*. You created an infinite loop.

Comment: When I run it now it all works, but the seconds appear as "str(x) second(s)" any idea how to make it show the string "str(x)". And the minutes never change.

Comment: @Minigeek22: You have two `Label()` calls in your function, the first is `mlable = Label(mGui,text = "str(x) second(s)").pack()`; that includes a literal `"str(x) "` string in it. Replace that too with my version.

Comment: There is one last issue the seconds and minutes not update. But otherwise thankyou.

Comment: You'll have to research how to use threads, I fear. You cannot update the UI continuously from a function directly started by the UI.